# CSS animate webkit-scrollbar

Tags: css, scrollbar

I'm new to HTML and I'm trying to learn how to create a custom scrollbar. I made it so when you hover over the 1px scrollbar it becomes 12px wide:

`::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 12px; }`

`*:hover::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 1px; }`

`::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{ border-radius: 6px; background: linear-gradient(transparent , #00ffff); }`

I want to animate that change so it becomes a smooth transition.
Is it possible somehow?

I didn't know where to start so I didn't try anything.